# Python precision when iterating through list?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, decimal, precision

I have a list of values which is iterated.  When the nTH item from the list defines a variable within the iter-loop, it does not represent the original list-item precision; ergo - decimal places are lost.

Simply printing each item type in the list returns floats for all, as does the nTH item type - yet the list and nTH item represent two **different** values; one a couple decimal places short.

This must be avoided, as this value is checked in a >= / <= routine later on.  With the missing decimal places, the only result is 4 week old foo-bar pie.

Perhaps some code and script screen-grab would help:

```
                        for J in range(lastRow,firstRow):
                        print 'rows', range(lastRow,firstRow)
                        theYintersect = horizontalGridLines[J]
                        print theYintersect
                        ...
                        scanningVertices = False
                        print horizontalGridLines
```

Where '*theYintersect*' is derived from the '*horizontalGridLines*' list; respectively group highlighted in the image link below:

[Script Editor Screen-Grab](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FQ0/PQYA/I4J7GV4X/FQ0PQYAI4J7GV4X.png)

Why would this occur, and can it be remedied without use of 'Decimal' module?

Thanks for any wisdom.

Comment: Please show working code with example numbers, that show the problem.

Comment: I don't 100% understand your problem, but I think it's worth mentioning that a floating point number can have different `str` and `repr` representations, so it will look different depending on whether you print the float directly, or print a collection (such as a list) that contains the float. One will have more apparent precision than the other.

Comment: Daniel, the code is for a stand-alone piece of software: so it didn't seem appropriate to paste the whole sha-bang.  Kevin, it sounds like what your getting at might be my problem--but as Mark states, this shouldn't be an issue, as I am working with Python 3+.

Comment: @Kevin they changed that in Python 3, `str` and `repr` give the same number of digits.

Comment: If you use comparisons on floating point numbers, be prepared for a world of pain. See any number of posts here on StackOverflow about floating point accuracy.

Comment: Would there be a better means of evoking this problem;  Why would a iterated value from a list return differently than it exists within that list?

Comment: @Katalpa: you say you're using Python 3+, but given that your code uses `print 'rows', range(lastRow,firstRow)` which is Python 2-only syntax, I don't think that can be right.

Comment: DSM, perhaps you are correct - the python ver. I am using is implemented within other software, it seems their latest release uses 2.7.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Wow.  2 down votes in less than 20 min.  I figured I was a poor coder and communicator, but this is a new achievement!  Anyhow, calling a print repr(theYintersect) returns the full float value, as the answer below distinguishes.  Even though apparently this was a poor question, I thank those highly who responded so quick.  On to figure-out why the >= / <= doesn't fare well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This apparent change in precision is because the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) representation of a float may contain more digits than the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) representation of that same float. objects printed directly use `str`, and objects within a collection such as a list use `repr`. Ex:

```
>>> repr(1/3.0)
'0.3333333333333333'
>>> str(1/3.0)
'0.333333333333'
>>> print [1/3.0]
[0.3333333333333333]
>>> print 1/3.0
0.333333333333
```

... But rest assured, even though the representations vary, the actual stored value remains the same. Comparison with >= and <= should behave consistently regardless of how you're displaying the numbers.

Comment: Your reply greatly improved my grasp on this subject.  Perhaps something else is a miss in my script...